# second fragment run in first fragment and third in second

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, view

My requierment is when I click the button in firstfragment load meaning from database ,then screen move to next screen (swipe to secondfragment) automaticaly image load from given url and display in image, then swipe to thirdfragment automatically audio load from given url, and same task for video.

Given code imagefragment(second fragment) load in meaningfragment(first fragment) and third in second, and fourth in third.

```
***Meaning fragment( First Fragment)***

String url2 = "";
String webdata = "";
int wifi = 0;
int first = 1;
View view;
List<String> wordslist;
ImageButton find;
EditText word;
WebView data;
TextView urdu_meaning;
ListView lv;

SqlLiteDbHelper dbHelper;
GetMeaning urdu ;
NetworkInfo mWifi;
ConnectivityManager connManager;
WifiManager wifiManager;
public static String urlword = "";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meaningview, container, false);
        word = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.word);
        find = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.find);
        data = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web);
        urdu_meaning = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Urdu_Text);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listofword);
        Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "jameel.ttf");
        urdu_meaning.setTypeface(tf);

        if(first == 1)
        {
            try {
                dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(getActivity());
                dbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            first++;

        }
        word.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!word.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
                {

                    wordslist = dbHelper.Loadwords(word.getText().toString());
                    //wordslist.toString()
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, wordslist);
                    lv.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    data.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    urdu_meaning.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                word.setText(wordslist.get(position));
                lv.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        find.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "DefaultLocale" })
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                lv.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                data.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                urdu_meaning.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                url2 = word.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

                AudioFragment.audioclick = 0;
                VideoFragment.videoclick = 0;
                ImageFragment.imageclick = 0;
                urlword = url2;
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);


                if(url2.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Word is missing! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try{

                        urdu = dbHelper.getDetail(word.getText().toString());
                        urdu_meaning.setText(urdu.Meaning.toString());
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        urdu_meaning.setText("Urdu word not found");
                    }


                    if (mWifi.isConnected())
                    {
                        data.loadUrl(url1 + url2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

***Image Fragment Second Fragment***

if(imageclick == 0)
        {
            //imageURL1 = imageURL + MeaningFragment.urlword + ".jpg";
            word.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // Execute the task
            //GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            //task.execute(imageURL1);
            // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
        }

        find.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "DefaultLocale" }) @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(imageclick == 0)
                {
                    imageURL2 = MeaningFragment.urlword.toString().toLowerCase();
                    word.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    word.setText(MeaningFragment.urlword.toString().toLowerCase());
                    prevword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    word.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prevword.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageURL2 = word.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

                }

                mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                if(imageURL2.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Word is missing! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {

                    imageURL2 = imageURL2 + ".jpg";
                    imageURL1 = (imageURL + imageURL2);
                    //searchurdu();


                    if(mWifi.isConnected())
                    {

                        try{


                            // Execute the task
                            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
                            task.execute(imageURL1);
                            // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask



                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        //task.execute("http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/node-cover-720x340.png");

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                    else
                    {           
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

            }


        });

        return view;
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try{
                Bitmap map = null;
                for (String url : urls) {
                    map = downloadImage(url);
                }return map;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;
            }




        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //pDialog.show();
        }
        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(result == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            try {Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;


            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
            return bitmap;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

                return null;
            }


        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            try {InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();


            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }return stream;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Word not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;

            }


and same method for audio and video.....
```

Comment: can you explain more clear ?

Comment: when start the application first Meaningfragment run and then on swipe image fragment. I am want enter word in edit txt and press find button show meaning and swipe for image fragment automatically load image from url and display in image view without enter text in edittxt and click on find button.

Comment: attached .apk file for more understanding.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp3dhw4vthp9ecf/joltadictionary.apk?dl=0

Comment: Did you find the solution?